# push(Element) method implementation in Stack

Tags: java, stack

I am learning Stack today.
I am trying to implement push(Element) method, but for some reasons it is not working.

I have added 10 items to my stack, then using toString method I print. The only item prints is my most Top Element.
Your help would be greatly appreciated!.

```
private Node head = null;
private Node tail = null;
private static int size;

public void push(Customer custPair)
{
    if (head == null)
    {
        head = new Node(custPair, null);
        tail = head;
        size++;
    } else
    {
        tail.next = head;
        head = new Node(custPair, null);
        size++;
    }

}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Walk down the list and append all values
    Node curNode = head;
    while (curNode != null)
    {
        sBuilder.append(curNode.value.toString()).append("\n");
        curNode = curNode.next;
    }
    return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong when the stack already has a head.  I think the new head must point to old head (via .next).

I'm bit confused, are you implementing a LIFO or FIFO stack?

For a LIFO

```
else {
    Node node = new Node(custPair, null);
    node.next = head;
    head = node;
    size++;
}
```

For a LIFO Stack, you really don't need a tail.

Comment: Last In First Out (LIFO)

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you.I was not aware of the tail part, thank you for updating. :)